# Apache Solr commandline reference for windows 10

Tags: solr, solrj

I would like to learn Apache Solr using Windows 10 , Could you kindly share any Apache Solr Reference manual for Windows 10 Command line interface. I want to venture the Solr using Windows.

Comment: The Solr control script reference is identical on nix and Windows: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/solr-control-script-reference.html#solr-control-script-reference

Comment: Thanks MatsLindh , I am more keen on the Solr Commands that can be run with post.jar and how it can be used as well on the resembling REST API  and it's equivalent SolrJ approach . Appreciate your response . For 8.4.1 has post.jar in the exampleDocs and command line reference in online is very feeble to find.

Comment: The POST tool is documented here: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/post-tool.html - The main indexing API is documented here: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/uploading-data-with-index-handlers.html - For other API endpoints, using the reference guide and looking at the requests the admin interface makes to your Solr core (with your browser's development tools) is the easiest way. SolrJ is a client; there are many available for multiple programming languages. The clients are usually thin layers on top of the REST API.

Comment: solr <command> -help  , is much more like an Unix Man Page help ...It helps to the intention of the command author based on the command.